# Lanscape orientation in Firefox

Tags: php, firefox, imagick, pdf.js

Today I noticed that PDF generated from our system through imagick is printed not correctly from Firefox [From Chrome it's ok], I mean page with landscape orientation is printed like portrait.

I read following articles

1. https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/9297
2. https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/6696

But I think they should be "kidding". Why should user know about some pdfjs and it's enablePrintAutoRotate option? It must be known by browser automatically.

I looked for available option like enablePrintAutoRotate for imagick but it seems it does not have it. Also if I click at info button in pdf page on Firefox, browser gives me that page's orientation is landscape.

So could someone please give me advice how to resolve current situation

Comment: This is a browser issue, it has nothing to do with Imagick or PHP; simply a setting in Firefox.

Comment: Are you sure dude? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's a known open bug in Firefox

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1406098

**UPDATE:**
Seems to be resolved with the new Print UI.